# apache stopped working suddenly port changing was useless

Tags: php, apache, xampp, port

I have XAMPP installed in my computer and he worked well till now. I have not installed anything new. I tried to change the port form 8080 to another port but it was useless. 
the messages form XAMPP panel:

```
3:20:30 PM  [Apache]    Attempting to start Apache app...
3:20:36 PM  [Apache]    Problem detected!
3:20:36 PM  [Apache]    Port 80 in use by "Unable to open process" with PID 4!
3:20:36 PM  [Apache]    Apache WILL NOT start without the configured ports free!
3:20:36 PM  [Apache]    You need to uninstall/disable/reconfigure the blocking application
3:20:36 PM  [Apache]    or reconfigure Apache and the Control Panel to listen on a different port
3:20:36 PM  [Apache]    Attempting to start Apache app...
3:20:36 PM  [Apache]    Status change detected: running
3:20:37 PM  [Apache]    Status change detected: stopped
3:20:37 PM  [Apache]    Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
3:20:37 PM  [Apache]    This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, 
3:20:37 PM  [Apache]    improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
3:20:37 PM  [Apache]    Press the Logs button to view error logs and check
3:20:37 PM  [Apache]    the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
3:20:37 PM  [Apache]    If you need more help, copy and post this
3:20:37 PM  [Apache]    entire log window on the forums
```

Comment: If you pull up a Cmd and type *Netstat -abno* you'll get a list of applications/services that are currently running and which ports they're using... look for something that's already using port 80 : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198/how-can-you-find-out-which-process-is-listening-on-a-port-on-windows

Comment: this comment is not working - the cmd said: The requested operation requires elevation.

Comment: @CD001 It shows that in the row of port 80 the state is LISTENING and foreign address is 'pc name:0'